# Fill a second select list using the vaule selected in first select box- Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, select

I have a ZF form with 2 select boxes. Both should fill from 2 DB tables. First select box will be filled when the form get rendered at first. (So this is done and working fine)
Then I want to fill the second select box by taking the value of the first select box when a value is  selected by the user and pass it to the select SQL to get the second set of data.

And I don't want the page to be refreshed. (So ajax/javascript/jquery)

I have following in my view (.phtml)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#make').change(function($e){
    $e.preventDefault();
     var href= "index/load";
     var data = 'make_id='+$('#make').val();
     $.ajax({ type: "POST",
           url: href,
          data: data,
          success: function(response){
            location.href = 'index/load';
         }
     });
});
});

</script>
```

but I cannot access the value passed from the ajax post using following in my controller action

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams('make_id');
```

Comment: Yes it is `ajax/javascript/jquery`. But what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have edit my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a simple way of doing it, in my view phtml I have the following,

```
 <body>
 <?php
     $this->form->setAction($this->url());
     echo $this->form;

  ?>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#select1').change(function(){
           $('#Myform').submit();
           return false;
       });
   });

   </script>
</body>
```

And in my controller action I have

```
public function viewAction()
{

        $form= new Application_Form_Myform();
        $selectbox1 = $form->getElement('select1');
        $selectbox1->setMultiOptions($this->populateselectbox1()); //This function fetch data from the db and make an array
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('select1')!=""){
            $selectbox2 = $form->getElement('select2');
            $selected = $this->getRequest()->getPost('select1');
            $select->setMultiOptions($this->populatselectbox2($selected)); //This function fetch data from the db and make an array
            $selectbox1->setValue($selected);
        }
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` part of an ajax request requires a `JSON` object like this `{make_id: something}`, so you will have to send parameters in this format:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#make').change(function($e){
  $e.preventDefault();
   var href= "index/load";
   var data = $('#make').val();
   $.ajax({ type: "POST",
     url: href,
     data: {make_id: data},
     success: function(response){
     location.href = 'index/load';
   }
 });
```

});

Comment: Did you saw that the `var data` has changed? Did you check if `$('#make').val()` is getting a real value?

Comment: Did you debug in `firebug/developer tools` if the `ajax` call is being made to the server? Did you check if the `$e.preventDefault()` is not getting in the way of making the ajax call?

Comment: I didnt want the $e.preventDefault() so I removed it. But still the same. and Fierbug doesn't show the post request any more, it was there before :(